# Ergotamine v Sumatriptan for migraine without aura

Tags: medications

[A randomized, double-blind comparison of sumatriptan and Cafergot in the acute treatment of migraine. The Multinational Oral Sumatriptan and Caferg... - PubMed - NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1653139)

> It is concluded that oral sumatriptan was well tolerated and is a more effective acute treatment for migraine than Cafergot.

Then why [many UKers](https://www.drugs.com/answers/cafergot-discontinued-604344.html) still want Ergotamine? [NHS Southampton Joint Formulary](http://www.southamptonformulary.nhs.uk/searchresults.asp?SearchVar=triptan&Submit2=Search) lists Almotriptan, Sumatriptan, Zolmitriptan.  Pls ELI5.

Comment: Hi there. You say many “UKers” still want ergotamine, but the link is a single person asking on a forum because it was discontinued. I don’t think many people are using it anymore. The BNF still lists it as a treatment for cluster headache but notes that this is unlicensed. As you say, triptans are generally more effective and, more importantly, much safer.

Comment: @Chris That single person got a lot replies from other people that also want Ergotamine.

Comment: True, but it’s a forum post, not a source from which we could deduce the level of use of or demand for ergotamine. She seems to have tried triptans and found them not as effective, so it’s natural she would prefer ergotamine. The evidence for the superiority of triptans in efficacy and safety does not mean they are better in every individual case.